# Finding the related tags by name by sunspot solr search in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-taggable-on

i am working on rails 3 and using acts_as_taggable_on gem

I have blog,Article associated with tags.

I am using `Blog.tagged_with(tag.name)` // which returns the array of blogs associated with tags

Now i am trying to fetch the tags related to my tag

My Tag is

```
 #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 1, name: "tag1">
```

when i fetch using  `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.first`

how to find the tags related to my tag by name. I am using Sunspot Solr search. 
Please suggest

Comment: Why you speak about sunspot ? You don't use it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplest way can be :

```
Blog.tagged_with(tag.name).map(&:tags).uniq
```